# MYSQL PHP user priveleges

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of making a backend for our company. I want to basically have 3 user groups... ADMIN with access too all functions, MANAGERS with access to all but ADMIN tasks, and USER with the most limited capabilities.

I was looking at how MySQL handles users, and is a pretty good system, but seems like quite a bit of overhead in coding something similar.

I was wondering if anybody else had suggestions.  I would like to make group management dynamic, but am wondering if it is worth it since we are a small company.

I will build a table that looks something like this. Assume GroupID 1 is ADMIN and GroupID 2 is User:

```
PRIVILEGE     GroupID    Grant
USER_ADD      1          "Y"
USER_ADD      2          "N"
EDIT_LISTING  1          "Y"
EDIT_LISTING  2          "Y"
```

and so on...
Here are the 3 options I am looking at:

1. Build a user class where a user logs in, class is instantiated and properties are set.  I don't like this because a new instance has to be created every time the user moves around
2. Save the query results (SELECT * FROM priveleges WHERE GroupID=:userGroup) to a global array
3. Keep the values in $_SESSION variables.  Is this secure enough to use?

Comment: when i do this i keep the user level in the session with the user id\name.

Comment: @Dagon, thanks, if the zend idea doesn't work out thats probably the way i will go.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to reinvent the wheel (unless you want to learn from it). Have you had a look at the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com), which comes with an own [Authentication](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html) and [Authorization](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html)-Module?

Comment: I was leaning more toward CodeIgnitor but I am so far along in this project, I was wondering about how much re-doing of the site I would have to do.  This project has already turned out more an undertaking than we anticipated.  I agree with you on reinventing the wheel, tho

Comment: You don't have to rewrite everything. The Zend Framework Modules are only loosely coupled and you may only use the two modules you really need and keep the rest of your present homepage.

Comment: Yea I was just over at their documentation checking it out..I might try to implement it.. I was afraid I would have to run the whole thing under Zend, but doesn't look as scary as i thought.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I like to handle this situation.

1. Create a User class with all of the user info including permissions/group
2. When the user logs in, save their user object as a session variable and just reference that session variable throughout all of your site.
3. Create your pages so that they only display options/functions that are allowed for the current user's permission level.

For example:

```
<?php
    $Me = new User(user parameters);
    $_SESSION['currentUser'] = $Me;

    ...

    if($_SESSION['currentUser']->GetValue(Permission) == 'Admin')
    {
        echo 'You're an admin';
    }
?>
```

That way you only do the user query once unless they change/update their information. You also don't have to do queries related to permissions which saves server overhead and time.

Comment: I started building a class, but was confused about how to make it work without asking the DB everytime somebody did something..thanks for the obvious idea i over looked!